# Having Difficulty Using cURL and PHP to Login and Download

Tags: php, curl, authentication, download, libcurl

Here is the code that I am using to try and accomplish this:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'linkToLoginPage.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'email=email@example.com,password=password');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'linkToDownloadFile.pdf');
$content = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 

?>
```

I set it up with my information, but it just produces a blank page.  I think my main issue is with the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.  [Here is the link to the page I am trying to login](http://www.mid-east.com/acclogin.asp?url=AL&msg=036&from=CheckCookie&FgtPass=).

I looked at the source code but I cannot find a clear definition of the form values.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is the worst use of nested tables I've seen in a long time, but the form fields are right there in the form; look for `<input>` tags.

Comment: Thanks Woodble.  I had a look found the input names on the nested tables.  I am still unable to get the code above to function as needed.  Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
curl_setopt($ch, 
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            'email=email@example.com&password=password' );
```

(`&` not `,`)

Comment: Which comma are you referring to?  I do not see a percent sign in your example.

Comment: `email=email@example.com&password=password` was originally `email=email@example.com,password=password`

Comment: Apparently, I originally had a typo in the (& not ,). Thank you for fixing it wooble.

Comment: I tried with the commas as you suggested and it still is blank.  Could it have something to do with the cookie.txt file?  Or could it have to do with the radio buttons on the form?

Comment: I wrote that backwards.  I tried it with the & sign and it still did not work.

Comment: Finally got it to work.  I used the & as you mentioned and then had to add some header information at the bottom of the page.